# How can I insert new rows into a query result using PL/SQL or SQL query in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am selecting data from multiple tables and want to insert data for missing years. Can I do this by using `PLSQL` or `SQL` ?

For example, below is output of my query:

```
YEAR  COUNT
----- -----
2012      5
2013      6
2015      2
2016      1
2019      0
```

I want to add the `year` and `count=0` for missing years and finally I should have this -

```
YEAR  COUNT
----- -----
2012      5
2013      6
2014      0
2015      2
2016      1
2017      0
2018      0
2019      0
```

Comment: Sample data would help a lot.

Comment: Wait a minute. How did you get [2019, 0] but not 2014? Could you post your original query?

Comment: Hey Gen, Good question. The developer was able to insert current year count as 0 if missing. So that's why you see [2019,0]. The original query is very complex and long and will not be helpful. So I created a simple prototype using just two columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be using `connect by level <= ..` syntax containing a `left join` with  `min(..) over (partition by ..)` and `max(..) over (partition by ..)` analytic functions as quxiliary :

```
with t as
(
 select t0.*, 
        min(year) over (partition by 1) as min_year,
        max(year) over (partition by 1) as max_year
   from t0
)
select t1.year as "year", nvl( t."count" , 0) as "count"
  from
  (
   select distinct level + t.min_year - 1 as year
     from t
   connect by level <= t.max_year - t.min_year + 1 ) t1
  left join t
    on t.year = t1.year
 order by "year"
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d7c95985c191394f8123cb12a9e983e8)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks much!!!! This is exactly what I was looking for. Works for me without creating   any new tables.

Answer (score 1):

Create a table `years` including the year values.

```
Create table years ( year int)
insert into years values (2010),(2011),(2012), ... etc
```

Then all you need to use is left join like below:

```
SELECT y.year,ISNULL(t.val,0)
FROM years y
LEFT OUTER JOIN yourtable t ON t.year=y.year
ORDER BY y.year
```

Comment: Thank you!! this seems like a good solution.. But wont completely help me because of few limitations. 1.)I can only read data from this database so I can't create the years table.  2) Every time the output is going to contain different years and I want to insert year and count after the least minimum year. So for this example above, I want the results only from 2012. And in another case if the min year is 2015, then I want the results only from 2015.